# Netbeans subversion form error

Tags: svn, forms, matisse, netbeans6.1

Well i'm having a problem which appeared i think when i rollbacked a .form file from subversion.
The NB 6.1 can open the .form but when i try to save the file the IDE throws an out of memory exception.

In NB 6.5 i can open and save the file but the IDE is behaving very strange:every  1 min or so freezes for 20 sec and then unfreezes.

Ok if anyone knows what i'm talking about plz help.
I think the problem starts from a corrupted .form file but it's strange for all the IDE to freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think the answer is to get more ram or try to free some ram for netbeans to be stable.Of course some very strange behaviors appear when the ram is at the limit.So try not to find out for your self